# Upgrading one phone by copying the update file from an identical phone

Tags: updates

I have two HTC One X - first one (which was bought in India) got upgraded OTA to JB 4.1 (official version pushed by HTC) last week. I might have to wait a few more weeks/months to get the same update on the second phone since it was bought in Europe.

Is there a way to update OS to 4.1 on the second phone by copying the update file from the first? Any changes need to be done before doing that?